# Почему мой код не умножает матрицу на матрицу а выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, умножение

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np

n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
A = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
input()
B = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
print(np.dot(A, B))
```

Моя ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 6, in <module>
    print(np.dot(A,B))
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

Тестовые данные:

```
2 2
1 2
3 2

2 2
3 2
1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`
   Правильно, но я в дальнейшем коде не вижу употребление переменной `m`.
2. `A = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]`
   Вы получите список **списков строк**, а не список чисел (и отсутствует перевод на `int` или `float`).
3. `input()`
   Вы хотите от пользователя ввод, но не сохраняете его в переменной
   (т.е. просто бросите его, нигде его не употребляя).
4. `B = [input().split()for _ in range(n)]`
   То же самое, что для `B` - см. 2.
5. `print(np.dot(A,B))`
   Не возможно умножить 2 списка с элементами типа `str`.

Comment: В третьем пункте ТС пропускает пустую строку. Это нормально.

Comment: Забыли размер второй матрицы прочитать.

Comment: А как преобразовать элементы списка в целые числа?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы пытаетесь перемножить строки. `input()` всегда возвращает строку, поэтому A и B содержат списки строк вида

```
A: [['1', '2'], ['3', '2']]
B: [['3', '2'], ['1', '1']]
```

Поэтому эти строки нужно преобразовать в целые числа, например, с помощью метода [`numpy.ndarray.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), предварительно преобразовав списки в `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np

strings="""2 2
1 2
3 2
2 2
3 2
1 1""".split('\n')

def input():
    global strings
    return strings.pop(0) + '\n'

n, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
A = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
input()
B = [input().split()for _ in range(m)]
print(np.dot(np.array(A).astype(int),np.array(B).astype(int)))
```

```
[[ 5  4]
 [11  8]]
```

Comment: Размер второй матрицы надо читать. Он не обязательно равен размеру первой матрицы.

Comment: Моя программа должна считывать две матрицы и перемножать их. Тоесть чему равен strings программе неизвестно пока пользователь сам не напишет две матрицы с их размерами.

Answer (score 0):

Вход устроен так: строка с размерами первой матрицы, строки со строками первой матрицы, пустая строка, строка с размерами второй матрицы, строки со строками второй матрицы. Логично сделать функцию для чтения матрицы.

Вижу две ошибки: данные матриц не переводятся из строк в числа, во второй матрице не прочитаны её размеры. Исправляем:

```
import numpy as np


def read_matrix():
    # пропустить m, но проверить формат
    n, _ = map(int, input().split())

    # прочитать n строк матрицы
    return [
        list(map(int, input().split()))
        for _ in range(n)
    ]


def main():
    m1 = read_matrix()  # прочитать первую матрицу
    input()             # пропустить пустую строку
    m2 = read_matrix()  # прочитать вторую матрицу

    print(m1)
    print(m2)
    print(np.dot(m1, m2))
    

main()
```

> ```
> $ cat input.txt
> 2 2
> 1 2
> 3 2
>
> 2 2
> 3 2
> 1 1
>
> $ python matrices.py < input.txt
> [[1, 2], [3, 2]]
> [[3, 2], [1, 1]]
> [[ 5  4]
>  [11  8]]
> ```